# Mist Error "Couldn't connect to node"

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby

I have `Mist 0.9.0` and `Geth 1.6.7` running on `Windows 8.1 x64`.

**Why am I get this error message when I open Mist?**

[image]

What I did:

```
geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby init C:\projects\rinkeby\rinkeby.json
geth --datadir=$HOME/.rinkeby
```

In another prompt window

```
geth --rinkeby attach
```

And double click on `Mist.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I run mist.exe as administrator. It worked.